# CodeIgniter update() defaults to insert()

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update

Is this possible / true?

For instance, if I want to update a row with the id of 1, but no row exists, will this function (update function) automatically ***insert*** a new row with the given data? Is there a parameter to enable this?

If not, what would be the best way to handle this (if possible) without using a separate function to evaluate the table and return bool if the row exists. (Then UPDATEing or INSERTing from there)

Not much of an issue.. Just looking for clarification and wondering if anyone knows about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps what you are looking for is this [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) - provided that you are using MySQL and your `id` is a unique key on the table.

You'd have to manually construct the query and pass to the `$this->db->query()` function instead of any built in active record like helper functions of the DB Driver.

Answer (score 8):

I found a good solution in this [link](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/72906/#360915), I hope it helps if anyone is still looking for a solution in **codeigniter**:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO menu_sub (id, name, desc, misc)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
            name=VALUES(name), 
            desc=VALUES(desc), 
            misc=VALUES(misc)';

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array( $id, 
                                       $this->validation->name, 
                                       $this->validation->desc, 
                                       $this->validation->misc
                                      ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't why would you use this, but one way to handle this (with one function as you requested) is the following:

```
function update_or_insert($data){

    if(!array_key_exists('id',$data))
        return $this->db->insert($data);

    $row = $this->db->get_where('mytable',['id' => $data['id']])->row();

    if(!$row) return false;

    $this->db->where($row->id);
    return $this->db->update('my_table',$data); 
}
```

$data can be a whole $_POST array passed from the controller. I would place this function inside the model that represents the table (my_table).

This is one solution that should work. Let us know.